# How to send my location with text message?

Tags: android

Only text message is able to send through this code but I don't know how to code for to send current location link with text message

```
    case R.id.button7:

    Intent i1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    i1.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 700000000"));
    startActivity(i1);

     try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("70000000", null, "hello", null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }}
```

Comment: You can send user's latitude and longitude as texts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: how can I send latitude and longitude as texts? Can you provide code

Comment: Where do you want to append your location?
After `hello`?

Comment: my location coding is in second activity and I want to pass it in first activity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it to the SMS message you need a way to recover it from the rest of the message.

Just define a separator character that will never be used on the text.

Example:

"hello|3.3452|22.2323"

Once you receive that string on the other side you can use

```
String.split("|");
```

That will return an array containing this:

```
[0]"hello"
[1]"3.3452"
[2]"22.2323"
```

Just knowing that Lat will be always at position 1 Long at 2 and the text message at 0

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To send user's location as TextMessage you need to get Latitude and Longitude of the phone, you can do that by.

```
GPSTracker mGps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
double latitude = mGps.getLatitude();
double longitude = mGps.getLongitude();
```

Now to send it as a TextMessage, you need to use `SmsManager`. Use this function in your button press.

```
protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");
        double latitude = mGps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mGps.getLongitude();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String phoneNo = mTxtphoneNo.getText().toString();//get phone number from the textView of the editText or wherever you have feeded the number
        String message = "These are my co-ordinates:-" + latitude + ", "
                + longitude + "\nAddress:-";

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS sent with current latitude and logitude",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```